# How to check if a field w/ certain value is missing in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

My `MongoDB` database contains records w/ such sample information as follow:

```
{_id:5fe206baad98b1198a5f688d,
ticker:"A",
date:"2020-12-18",
open:119.2300033569336,
close:119.30000305175781,
adjclose:119.30000305175781,
high:119.86000061035156,
low:118.44000244140625,
vol:3911800
}
```

However, the data vendor occasionally doesn't provide all data. For example, I received data for all the other stocks on December 1st, 2020, but the Apple stock data is missing for that date. Under such circumstances, the `2020-12-01` data of the Apple stock is missing in the database.

I want to find out which stocks don't contain a date field with value of `2020-12-01`. I have tried something like `$exists:true`, but it only applies to `Field`, but to a field with a specific value.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to find all records where `date` is not equal to `2020-12-01`, also including records that have no `date` field at all?

Comment: `$exists:false` is all you need

Comment: John, what I want is all records that don't contain the pair {'date':'2020-12-01'}

Comment: Minsky, $exists:false is not what I want because a record w/o the field and value of {'date':'2020-12-01'} is not inserted into database at the begining.

Comment: All individual record in the database has a {'date': somedate} field. But some stock tickers have no {'date':'2020-12-01'}, but all other tickers do. I want to find those w/o {'date':'2020-12-01'}

Comment: How would the records for apple be like, in this case? just include that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution for you that will fit better:

```
db.t1.find({})
```

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe74967d3c3a4b9fe8dc5c2"), "ticker" : "A", "date" : "2020-12-19" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe7496dd3c3a4b9fe8dc5c3"), "ticker" : "B", "date" : "2020-12-19" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe74971d3c3a4b9fe8dc5c4"), "ticker" : "C", "date" : "2020-12-19" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe74979d3c3a4b9fe8dc5c5"), "ticker" : "A", "date" : "2020-12-20" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe74980d3c3a4b9fe8dc5c6"), "ticker" : "C", "date" : "2020-12-20" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe7498ad3c3a4b9fe8dc5c7"), "ticker" : "A", "date" : "2020-12-21" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe75139d3c3a4b9fe8dc5c8"), "ticker" : "N", "date" : "2020-12-25" }

```
db.t1.aggregate([ {$match:{date:"2020-12-20"}} , {$group:{_id:"All_having_the_date",  tickers:{$addToSet:"$ticker"}    }}  ]).forEach(function(d){ var all=db.t1.distinct("ticker");var e = all.filter(f => !d.tickers.includes(f));   print(e)    })
```

B,N

> 

Explained:
You fetch all tickers having date:"2020-12-20"  and extract from distinct tickers list those that are missing in the date:"2020-12-20"  , in the example above this are ticker B & ticker N .

Comment: please format the code properly. this hurts your eyes to read

Answer (score 0):

You can simply query for any missing fields , example searching the documents from date:"2020-12-18" that miss field "high" or field "vol" :

```
> db.test.find({ })
```

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe50e06977b2c66b4166afc"), "ticker" : "A", "date" : "2020-12-18", "open" : 1, "close" : 1, "adjclose" : 1, "high" : 1, "vol" : 3 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe50e15977b2c66b4166afd"), "ticker" : "A", "date" : "2020-12-18", "open" : 1, "close" : 1, "adjclose" : 1, "high" : 1 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe50e4b977b2c66b4166afe"), "ticker" : "A", "date" : "2020-12-18", "open" : 1, "close" : 1, "adjclose" : 1 }

> db.test.find({ date:"2020-12-18", $or:[ {vol:null} ,{ high:null } ] })

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe50e15977b2c66b4166afd"), "ticker" : "A", "date" : "2020-12-18", "open" : 1, "close" : 1, "adjclose" : 1, "high" : 1 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fe50e4b977b2c66b4166afe"), "ticker" : "A", "date" : "2020-12-18", "open" : 1, "close" : 1, "adjclose" : 1 }

> 

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't solve my problem. I want to find out which stock tickers don't contain a date field with value of 2020-12-01, rather than those tickers that contain the right date fields but other fields.

Comment: maybe something like this then:   > db.test.aggregate([  {$match:{date:{$nin:["2020-12-01"]}}} ,{ $group:{_id:"All_not_having_2020-12-01" , tickers:{$addToSet:"$ticker"} } }    ])
{ "_id" : "All_not_having_2020-12-01", "tickers" : [ "D", "B" ] }
>

Comment: I can't see your solution clearly. Could you post it as normal? By the way, "tickers" : [ "D", "B" ] can't be right because I can't add all the tickers in this statement.